# Databricks - Read CSV file from folder

Tags: azure, databricks

SELECT * from `dbfs:/FileStore/shared_uploads/prasanth/Company.csv`

I am trying to select the records from folder in azure data bricks but I am facing this
Error
**SQL statement: AnalysisException: Table or view not found**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I reproduced this got same error.

[image]

This error occurs when there is no table or view created earlier on that name in **databricks SQL**.
In the above, you are trying to query `dbfs:/filepath.csv` which is not a table or view in Databricks SQL.

To access `dbfs` file in databricks SQL, first we need to create a table or view for that and copy the csv file data into that. Then we can query that table.

**Code for that:**

```
%sql
/*Table creation with schema*/
CREATE OR REPLACE TABLE  table1
( 
Id int,Name varchar(32),Age int,marks int
);

/*Copying dbfs csv data into table*/
copy into table1
  from "dbfs:/FileStore/tables/mycsv2.csv"
  FILEFORMAT = csv
  FORMAT_OPTIONS('header'='true','inferSchema'='True');

select * from table1;
```

**My Execution:**

[image]

**Another alternative**(to query csv in databricks SQL) for this can be using **pyspark or scala dataframe** as suggested by **@ASH** above.

Read the csv file then create a temporary view.

**Code:**

```
%python
spark_df=spark.read.csv("dbfs:/FileStore/tables/mycsv2.csv",header=True)
#Creating temporary view for the dataframe.
spark_df.createOrReplaceTempView("mycsvview1")

%sql
select * from mycsvview1;
```

**Output for your reference:**

[image]

Answer (score 1):

With the latest Databricks version, you can use the below command:

`SELECT * FROM CSV. 'dbfs:/location/csv_files/'`

Comment: Do you know how/if we can specify options when reading csv? like `header=True, sep="|"` @Sameer Gupta

Answer (score 0):

Try it this way.

```
# in Python
flightData2015 = spark\
.read\
.option("inferSchema", "true")\
.option("header", "true")\
.csv("/data/flight-data/csv/2015-summary.csv")


// in Scala
import org.apache.spark.sql.types.{StructField, StructType, StringType, LongType}
val myManualSchema = new StructType(Array(
new StructField("DEST_COUNTRY_NAME", StringType, true),
new StructField("ORIGIN_COUNTRY_NAME", StringType, true),
new StructField("count", LongType, false)
))
spark.read.format("csv")
.option("header", "true")
.option("mode", "FAILFAST")
.schema(myManualSchema)
.load("/data/flight-data/csv/2010-summary.csv")
.show(5)
```